# Using wildcards/regex with variables in NGINX location

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

I have a nginx configuration that looks like this, where I serve different build versions at different paths. How can I do this using regex/wildcards? I need to be able to capture the path (PATH1, PATH2 etc.) as a variable and use it inside the alias directive as well.

```
    location /sitename/PATH1 {
      alias /some/fldr/PATH1;
      try_files $uri /sitename/PATH1/index.html;
    }

    location /sitename/PATH2 {
      alias /some/fldr/PATH2;
      try_files $uri /sitename/PATH2/index.html;
    }

    location /sitename/PATH3 {
      alias /some/fldr/PATH3;
      try_files $uri /sitename/PATH3/index.html;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64188034/using-wildcards-regex-with-variables-in-nginx-location

Comment: Is `PATH1` string equal in `location`, `alias` and `try_files` directives? And `PATH2` and `PATH3` too? And `/some/fldr/` path is the same in all three locations?

Comment: Yes, `/some/fldr` is the same in all three locations. The build for `/sitename/PATH{X}` lives in `/some/fldr/PATH{X}`

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
location ~ ^/sitename/(?<path>PATH1|PATH2|PATH3)(?<subpath>/.*)? {
    alias /some/fldr/$path/;
    try_files $subpath /sitename/$path/index.html;
}
```